# How can I get access to the systemItem information of the sender parameter of the function prepare for segue?

Tags: swift, parameters, prepared-statement, segue, any

By unwinding a segue I use the function `prepare(for:sender:)` to identify which button was pressed to run some code based on the outcome;
the information should be available within the parameter `sender` but I'm not able to read out the needed information although I can see the needed information would be there (systemItem=Save) when checking the debugger.

The debugger shows me the content of "sender": 
(lldb) po sender
▿ Optional
  - some :  target=0x600002e6aec0 action=perform: systemItem=Save

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    print("prepare called")
}
```

What I would expect is that I can check if the button clicked was "Save" and perform some code if true; How do I get a handle on the information needed?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get button info from `prepareForSugue...` func because this is not target. If you want to get pressed button info you may add target to your button with passing sender parameter like :

```
button.addTarget(self, #selector(handlePress(_:)))


@obj private func handlePress(_ sender: UIButton) {        
     // Do your logic here with button then
   self.perform(segueWithIdentifier: String)

}
```

`PrepareForSegue` method will call automatically  after you calling `preform(segue...)` func

Comment: well... "sender" is a parameter of the prepare function (sender: The object that initiated the segue. You might use this parameter to perform different actions based on which control (or other object) initiated the segue.) - therefor the parameter comes with the information I would need - see my initial description. the button "Save" is the trigger - the information is within the parameter as the log file clearly shows - but I don't know how to get a handle to that information.

Comment: you can use the information in the segue and sender parameters to disambiguate between different logical paths in your app. For example, if the segue originated from a table view, the sender parameter would identify the table view cell that the user tapped. You could then use that information to set the data on the destination view controller.